# Append existing sqlite3 database with cron

Tags: python, linux, bash, cron

I've created a python script (a webscraper) that writes its output to a sqlite database and I'm currently working on a django webapp to serve as its interface.

I've managed to connect the apps database to the django app, using the 'inspectdb'  command and the django app is able to display the contents of the database. I've set multiple cronjob (using crontab -e) to run the python script at a set interval (using different sys.argv parameters per run). Though the script is running, the output is saved not to the scripts directory (/home/projects/scraper_gui/gui) but instead to the /home directory.

Is there a way to direct cron to run the script in the scripts directory, instead in the home directory? I saw a few post mentions the *cronjob* >> *file location* method, but would not this overwrite the entire database? (Including all of the django-specific tables that have been added)

Kind regards,

Jasper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `cd` command in cron file like here (run your script after change directory):

```
0 12 * * * cd /my/dir/script && /usr/local/bin/python3 script.py
```

Comment: This solution is so simple that it never even occured to me. Thank you very much!